# Are there differing organelle to cytoplasm ratio in animal cells?

Tags: cell-biology

Could anyone provide me with examples of cells with high organelle to cytoplasm ratios (heavily packed), and examples of cells with low organelle to cytoplasm ratios (sparsely packed)?

Comment: If you want to sketch the cells, it might be easier to compare plant cells. Usually plant cells have a large vesicle contains fluid in the middle of the cell. However, root cells don't have this type of vesicles. It's the easiest to draw according to my knowledge.

Comment: Example of cell with low organelle to cytoplasm ratio : Red Blood Cell,Root cells(Root hair cell)
Example of cell with high organelle to cytoplasm ratio : Not sure about this...Fat cell , Sperm cell probably ?

Comment: This depends a bit on how you define the ratio. What precisely do you mean by "organelle" and "cytoplasm"? If you consider the entire cell volume as cytoplasm, then fat cells (adipocytes) would have an extremely low ratio, as nearly all of the cell volume is just fat. But if you consider cytoplasm to be just the water-soluble part, then it's very different. Also, a lot of cell structures are hard to classify as "organelles", for example glycogen and microtubules. Perhaps just the water content of a cell would be a good measure? That would include all macromolecules as "organelle" mass.

Comment: @Roland yeah i would exclude macro molecules, I'm talking about stuff like mitchondria...

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

The structure of a cell is highly related to its function. For example, a plasma B cell (a type of immune cell) contains lots of ER and Golgi because its job is to secrete antibodies, which are proteins, in your body. It has to create a lot of proteins, so a plasma B cell has a lot of organelles that help create, assemble and secrete proteins.

There are so many examples you can use.

Comment: can you give a low ratio example as well? I am computer scientist modelling cell internals so it's not really in my wheel house

Comment: @RRs_Ghost examples of animal cytoplasm ratio: see the difference between monocytes and other lymphocytes. Monocytes have larger "white" area under microscope, which is the cytoplasm area(so it has a more condensed nucleus and organelle complex. However it's not the case for other lymphocytes.